How to configure nginx to handle http and https perfectly?
i want to setup a simple server with nginx on this domain : livreur.ovh
what i want to display is a angular webpage ( basicaly a static html file )
the nginx webserver is dockerized in a container build with this file :
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/
VOLUME /app
VOLUME /certbot
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

the ssl certificates are generated by certbot (lets encrypt)
my dns records looks like this :
www IN CNAME livreur.ovh.
IN A 83.115.211.248

my server has ports 80 & 443 opened and the nginx conf is the following :
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/livreur.ovh/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/livreur.ovh/privkey.pem;
    
    server_name livreur.ovh www.livreur.ovh;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://livreur.ovh$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        root /app/dist/web/browser;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

}

it should render a basic angular template and some urls works but some doesnt and i cant figure out why
every http://* urls works and redirects to https://livreur.ovh except http://...:443 (ik its weird to make http request on port 443 but i dont want to leave holes in my conf)
which returns this :
coulo@livreurpi:~/web $ curl -L http://livreur.ovh:443
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.27.3</center>
</body>
</html>

how can i fix that ?
also the urls https://83.115.211.248:80/ and https://livreur.ovh:80/ cant connect but i tried on some websites and it doesnt seems to work too so ig i cant fix that
i also want to block the connexions (or redirects them) made by using the ip adress on https

I don't think the http://livreur.ovh:443 request is something that needs to be "fixed"; however, you have a way to do it using nginx custom 497 response HTTP code, as shown here. For your second question, refer this answer.

I think there is nothing to be fixed here except your expectations. You should not expect that plain http works on port 443, because you've configured it for https. You should also not expect that https works on port 80, because you've configure it for plain http. Surprisingly you did not complain that it does not work on any other port (like 22, 25, 465, ...) - which won't work either because you did not configure any services there at all or because there are different services (SSH, SMTP, ,...)

@SteffenUllrich the thing is for some website the port 443 on http work but idk how and why, i just wanted to know how to fix that

@TitouanCoulon: again, there is nothing to fix. There is no common expectation that plain http works on port 443 and thus there is no need to match this non-existing expectation. The expectation seems to be solely on your site.
